# Trying to get the address of a particular node of linkedlist in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, linked-list, memory-address, singly-linked-list

I am trying to print the address of a particular node in `c#`.

Here is the function which finds the minimum two elements(suppose `min1` and `min2`) in the existing linked list.
For some reasons i want to know the address of the first minimum occurred in the list(that may be min1 or min2, irrespective of which one is greater or which one is smaller, I just need to know the address of the first minimum found on traversal from head of the Linked List to NULL).

I tried to do so and my code is able to find the minimum two and also i tried to find the address of the first minimum element arrived on traversing from head in a `while loop` which `break`s and store the `address` in address variable and come out of the `loop`.

But the problem is instead of printing the value of address it prints a long `string` as given below:

```
shekhar_final_version_Csharp.Huffman+Node
```

where `shekhar_final_version_Csharp.Huffman` is the name of `namespace`.

Below is code :

```
public Node find_two_smallest(ref Node pmin1, ref Node pmin2) 
{
    Node temp = tree;
    Node address = tree;
    Node min1 ;
    min1 = new Node();
    min1.freq = int.MaxValue;
    Node min2;
    min2 = new Node();
    min2.freq = int.MaxValue;
    while (temp != null) 
    {
        if (temp.is_processed == 0) 
        {
            if (temp.freq < min2.freq) 
            {
                min1 = min2;
                min2 = temp;
            } 
            else if (temp.freq < min1.freq && temp.freq!=min2.freq) 
            {
                min1 = temp;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
    pmin1 = min1;
    pmin2 = min2;

    // Below is the code to find the address of first minimum arriving on traversal
    // of List.
    while (temp != null) 
    {
        if (temp.freq == min2.freq || temp.freq == min1.freq ) 
        {
            address=temp;
            break;
        } 

     }          
    // See below the output corresponding to it.
    Console.WriteLine("Address check: {0} Its value is : {1}", 
                      address, address.freq);
    return address;
}
```

It's corresponding output is:

```
Address check: shekhar_final_version_Csharp.Huffman+Node Its value is : 88
```

where it is showing correctly the value at that location (min1/min2=88) but not showing address, I want to see the integer value of the address.

Could some one please help me in achieving my target ?hanks.

When i try to see the address using `&` operaor it gives following error.

```
hp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Internship_Xav/c#$ gmcs check1.cs /unsafe
check1.cs(119,76): error CS0214: Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context
check1.cs(119,76): error CS0208: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type `shekhar_final_version_Csharp.Huffman.Node'
check1.cs(12,22): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?  This is exactly the kind of thing that you are not supposed to do (or care about) in Managed Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the memory address of a managed object like this.  It is simply not a supported feature of the language.

Comment: But is it sure that this "address" variable of Node type contains the address ?How to make it sure ?

Comment: @user234839 I have no idea what you're asking in that comment.

Comment: In c++ we use  "&" to do so. so the only way to know if address variable in my code contains the correctt address is to print the corresponding "freq" by doing "+address.freq".

Comment: @user234839 Yes, and this isn't C++, this is C#, and in C#, that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.WriteLine` calls `ToString()` on the objects passed to it and then prints this string. The default behavior of `ToString()` is to print the type name. If you want something else, override it in your classes:

```
public class Node
{
    ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value; // Or whatever properties you want to print.
    }
}
```

---

Note: In C# you cannot get the memory address of objects. This is because the garbage collector (GC) can relocate objects when collecting. If you need to identify an object, add your own identifier as a field or property. For instance with a `Guid` field:

```
public class Node
{
    private Guid _guid = Guid.NewGuid();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _guid;
    }
}
```

Or by using a static counter:

```
public class Node
{
    private static int _counter = 0;

    private int _id = _counter++;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _id;
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants it to print the location of that object in memory.  Even overriding the `ToString` method, he can't do that.

Comment: Does he really want to do that or does he talk about a `Node` called `address`?

Comment: [He really wants to do that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412844/trying-to-get-the-address-of-a-particular-node-of-linkedlist-in-c-sharp/22413134?noredirect=1#comment34079561_22413134)

Answer (score -1):

In c# to refer to the address of a refererence type use the '&' operator

```
Console.WriteLine("Address check: {0} Its value is : {1}", &address, address.freq);
```

Comment: i tried it but it gives error, please see the edited part of my question.

Comment: That is correct.  The use of 'pointers' or addresses in c# is restricted to "unsafe" code sections.  I probably should have mentioned this. :).  you need to wrap the code in an unsafe {} block.  I really don't recommend using addresses and pointers in c# in general, but if you insist, then the code must be labeled as unsafe.  see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx

Comment: You cannot get the address of a managed object like this.  You can only get the address of something that is fixed, even in an `unsafe` block.

Comment: @NebulaSleuth i even tried this "public unsafe Node find_two_smallest(ref Node pmin1, ref Node pmin2) " but don't work yet

Comment: @Servy Is there any alternative to see or print the value of address contained in it ?

Comment: @Servy - Yep your right.  My mistake.  Shows you how often I actually use this... never. I was under the impression that it worked for reference types, but I was wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: @NebulaSleuth even for reference we use  "ref" not "&" if i am correct.